# Structure issue C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that calculates the value of a resistor given three colour bands, four colours are set to a specific value. I have declared my colours as B, R, O, Y. I am having trouble entering a character to specify the value of resistance.

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense it's hard to explain.

The problem occurs on the scanf line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  typedef struct 
  {
    char B;
    char R;
    char O;
    char Y;
  }colour;

  colour library[4];
  {
    library[0].B = 1;
    library[1].R = 2;
    library[2].O = 3;
    library[3].Y = 4;
  }

  colour band_1, band_2, band_3;

  //Can enter either of 4 values? B, R, O, Y
  printf("Enter the colour of band 1: ");
  scanf("%c", &colour);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `colour` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: Also you are setting `B`, `R`, `O`, `Y` one at a time for 4 different `colour`s

Comment: `colour` is user defined struct type. Please elaborate what input you want to take from user and what output you are expecting ?

Comment: You appear to have a misunderstanding of structures, arrays and data types (and the way resistor colour codes work for that matter), so while your *syntactical* error may be in the scanf call, none of the code makes any sense *semantically* - consequently it is very difficult to answer this question in any way that would actually be useful to you.

Comment: Does it mean each band can have four possible color?

Comment: Yes it means each band can have four possible colours because the program does not yet know what value resistor you have. but if you say my method is flawed I shall try something else.

Comment: Your code looks so advance or so poor. I am not sure about your code. But for getting four color You have to use :
scanf("%c %c %c %c", &colour.B, &colour.R, &colour.O, &colour.Y);

Comment: You would take four boolean values as input from user. If user inputs **1 0 1 1**  for current band then you will come to know that **B, O, Y** colours are present in current band and R is missing